# How to control which github commits to build for in CircleCI?

Tags: git, github, circleci

I want to setup a CI such that it only reacts and builds when the git commits being reported by GitHub webhooks, contain changes for any content in a subfolder of my repo.

```
myRepo
> code1.js
> workers <-- run when this ... or anything under this changes
  > worker1.js
```

For example, I want to setup a CircleCI build that can look at the commits and run a script to decide a `go? or no-go?` for builds based on the commit-changelog matching a regular expression that searches for `workers` in the changelog payload.

I just don't know where to hook in and how:

1. should i setup my github webhook to be smarter somehow and discern if the changelog has anything mentioning the `workers` folder? This way my CI can stay dumb because the webhook makes the decision about when to push the commit-payload to the CI on its own.
2. should i hook in somewhere into CircleCI's yaml file somehow to discern if the changelog has anything mentioning the `workers` folder? if so where?

I can write my own regex but i need to know where to inject/hook-in a script.

---

Things I'm not asking for:

1. I'm not asking for alternatives like git submodules
2. I do not want to split up into two separate repos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CircleCI doesn't support this functionality built-in. On the CircleCI side, you sure can have some logic in `circle.yml` that checks for changes in the `workers` directory however we'll only evaluate that once the build process has already started. Not very efficient.

As far as GitHub webhooks, I wasn't aware something like that could be done. If so, that's awesome, please let me know.

**My Suggestion**

CircleCI does support the [`[skip ci] or [ci skip]`](https://circleci.com/docs/skip-a-build/) flag in the commit message. If changes outside of the `workers` directory is infrequent, simply add that flag to the commit message. If changes happen often, that'll be tedious so instead I'd use the Git `commit-msg` hook. You can write a small script for that hook to check which directories contained changes. If anything inside `workers/*` wasn't changed, append (or prepend) the commit message with `[skip ci]`. The Git docs is pretty bare here but here's the hooks page: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks.

I hope that helps.

-Ricardo
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: FYI: This has been turned into a blog post: https://circleci.com/blog/circleci-hacks-automate-the-decision-to-skip-builds-using-a-git-hook/